# Using query parameters in @Path annotation on client side

Tags: resteasy, quarkus

I'm working with Quarkus (2.0.2.Final)
This is my server side endpoint

```
class Endpoint {
    @Path("{userId}/password")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @PUT
    @Transactional
    public void changePassword(@QueryParam("action") String act, @PathParam("userId") long userId, AbstractPasswordResourceBean action) {...}
}
```

`@QueryParam` "action" can be one of "reset", "reset-request", "change" and body content will vary according to action.

On client side my idea is to remap this endpoint with 3 different methods, one for any action:

```
@RegisterRestClient
@Path("/users")
class ClientSide {
    @Path("{userId}/password?action=change")
    @PUT
    TokenResponse changePassword(@PathParam("userId") long userId, ChangePasswordBean request);

    @Path("{userId}/password?action=reset")
    @PUT
    TokenResponse resetPassword(@PathParam("userId") long userId, ResetPasswordBean request);

    @Path("{userId}/password?action=reset-request")
    @PUT
    TokenResponse requestResetPassword(@PathParam("userId") long userId, ResetPasswordRequestBean request);
}
```

Every call to one of above methods is resolved with a 404 because the url called is resolved as `http://service:port/service-name/users/{userId}/password%3Faction=...`; the error seems to be caused by querystring encoding.

Is this a bug or a by design behaviour? Or I am missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Path` annotation is not designed to accept a query string. Thus why it is escaped to become an acceptable path (agreed that's not what you want but that's how it works).

I don't think you'll be able to do what you want given how JAX-RS path matching works.